# Laravel Cron Job not executing Eloquent query

Tags: php, laravel

I just setup a cron job for a laravel project I'm currently working on. This is the handle function in my command.

```
public function handle()
    {
        Log::info("PayoutList Cron started!");

        $tradersToPay = Investments::select('id', 'monthly_roi')
                    ->where(DB::raw('CURDATE()'), '<=', 'end_date')
                    ->where(DB::raw('DAY(CURDATE())'), '=', DB::raw('DAY(start_date)'))
                    ->where('status', '=', 2)
                    ->get();
        foreach ($tradersToPay as $payout){
            $row = [
                'investment_id' => $payout->id,
                'roi' => $payout->monthly_roi,
                #'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
            ];
            Payouts::create($row);
        }
        #$this->info('PayoutList Cron command executed successfully');
        Log::info("PayoutList Cron command executed successfully");
    }
```

I have schedule this command to run daily at midnight and it only shows the Log message in the log files which means the command executed but the query in between is not working on my cpanel but working on my windows local server. I need help on this.

```
$schedule->command('payoutlist:cron')
                    ->dailyAt('02:30')
                    ->timezone('Africa/Lagos');
```

My host only allowed to set this on the cron job which still works fine

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/local/bin/php /directorty/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I'm using Laravel 5.8

Comment: It might be executing the query, but not getting any results for the foreach. Try `Log::info("There are ".$tradersToPay->count()." traders");` between your query and foreach.

Comment: Also, make sure the date/time on your mysql server match the date/time on your local server. If the mysql server is running at UTC and your local server is not, then the times you're looking for may not be matching up.

Comment: Hey @aynber I tried this `Log::info("There are ".$tradersToPay->count()." traders");` and this is what I got 
`[2020-08-28 16:25:39] local.INFO: PayoutList Cron command executed 0 records successfully` which the query is not returning any records

Comment: Also when I executed this query `SELECT * FROM investments WHERE CURDATE() <= end_date AND DAY(start_date) = DAY(CURDATE()) AND status=2` directly from the phpmyadmin, it returned 3 records. Can you help me that this query corresponds with Eloquent query I used in cron command.

Comment: Have you checked whether the query really translate into what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue stems from this line:

```
->where(DB::raw('CURDATE()'), '<=', 'end_date')
```

Laravel expects the third parameter to be a value, so it's passing `end_date` as a string instead of a column name. Since you're not passing any actual values, turn the whole where in a raw query:

```
->whereRaw('CURDATE() <= end_date')
```

Answer (score 0):

You Are using Raw query try using eloquent that will be for sure working , or compare DB version between local and online server

instead of DB::raw
use somethin like this  : where('end_date', '>=', date('Y-m-d').' 00:00:00'));

Comment: I don't think it is the raw query, I will try to compare the MySQL version of both online and my local server

Comment: How do i get the mysql version runniing on the cpanel?

Comment: or use : whereDate('created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));